TensorFlow - Replacement for normalize_utf8 to split accented characters
In order to split accented characters, I use tensorflow_text.normalize_utf8(x, 'NFKD')
Unfortunately, tensorflow_text is not avalaible on Windows after TF 2.10 in pip.
I am looking for a replacement of normalize_utf8 that does exactly the same thing and that works on Windows in TF 2.17.
Any hardcoded implementation would be great too.
Thanks in advance.
